# How to add querystring in Angular without effecting back history?

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, when the user selects a match percentage the URL gets updated with the new query string parameters for that value.

To do this, I am using the below. However, it adds to the users history. So if they were to hit the back button, it first counts adding the query string parameter as the first back step.

How can I add/change a query string parameter without the back button counting it as a step back? I tried using `skipLocationChange: true` but then the query string parameter is not added at all.

```js
#setMinMatchPercentageQueryParams(value) {                                        
  const queryParams = { 
    minMatchPercentage: value,                                                    
  };
      
  return this.router.navigate(                                                    
    [],
    {
      relativeTo: this.activeRoute,                                               
      queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',                                               
    },
  );  
}
```

Comment: You can use `skipLocationChange`, that will preserve the url but update the query params internally. Is it something that suits you ?

Comment: Other than that, the `replaceUrl` should do the same, but still update the url.

Comment: No, this will not work for me. Because `skipLocationChange: true` causes the url query string in the browser to not be updated (or added) at all. I need it to be added/updated in the url

Comment: `replaceUrl` worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add `replaceUrl` property and set it to true
Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to update the query parameters using `window.history.replaceState` method

Eg:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '',`/person/${personId}/${tabIndex}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, skipLocation don't change the url. But really it's not necesary change the url to get the "query", you can get the params subscribing to `activatedRouter.paramMap`

```
<div class="container">
    <a (click)="navigate('/one','one')">One</a> |
    <a (click)="navigate('/one','two')">Two</a> | 
    <a (click)="navigate('/one','three')">three</a> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

navigate(path:string,arg:string)
{
    this.router.navigate([path+"/"+arg],{skipLocationChange:true})
}
```

My component to check

```
@Component({
  selector: 'one',
  template: `<h1>One</h1>
  <pre>{{data$ |async}}</pre>
  `
})
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
  data$:any
  constructor(private activatedRouter:ActivatedRoute){}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.data$ = this.activatedRouter.paramMap.pipe(
      map((params:any) => params.get('id'))
    )
  }
}
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mhhbd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fone.component.ts)